# Commands to copy and paste

Tags: windows-10, powershell, batch, cmd.exe, vbscript

I want my powershell/batch/vbscript to be able to copy a text start notepad and then paste it I found how to copy which is [here](https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-copy-to-clipboard/) but I don’t know how to **paste it** any ideas how can I do it **without** third party tools?

Comment: What I would suggest you is to paste the text into a new file and then open the file using Notepad. This would produce same result, except that it will create a new file, but this will also save you a lot of effort, because doing it the other way seems to be difficult

Comment: And if you are using the ways mentioned in the link, You can instead just make a new file with the required text and open it using notepad. This way you won't even require copy pasting commands.

Comment: Yes but I want to copy and paste it to notepad which'll yes be harder to do

Comment: There's a reason it's harder -- it's poor coding! From the [Ciipboard class]() documentation: **`Security Alert: For security purposes, the following points should be kept in mind. Paste operations need to be user initiated (Ctrl-V, Paste Menu).`**

Answer (score 2):

This is a very common thing. A quick web search would show you many.

[powershell 'capture and send output to notepad'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=powershell%20%27capture%20and%20send%20output%20to%20notepad%20%27&t=h_&ia=web)

Just use SendKeys and pass CRTL+V.

Pass your content to the clipboard

Example:

```
Get-NetIPConfiguration | clip | notepad
Sleep -Seconds 1
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('^V')
```

Or use other pre-built examples that already exist for this use case as shown in the link provided.

Comment: I'd like to suggest using `scb` *alias* to `Set-ClipBoard` instead of using `Clip.exe`.

Comment: Choices, choices, choices..... it's always a prefernece.